# Run jquery each loop with a delay between each loop

Tags: jquery

Below I am using `$.each` to loop through the `seconds` array.

I am trying to delay each loop by 1 second. But having odd results with the method I am using.

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/mda4uf6c/

```js
// remove class regex
$.fn.removeClassRegEx = function(regex) {
  var classes = $(this).attr('class');
  if (!classes || !regex) return false;
  var classArray = [];
  classes = classes.split(' ');
  for (var i = 0, len = classes.length; i < len; i++)
    if (!classes[i].match(regex)) classArray.push(classes[i]);
  $(this).attr('class', classArray.join(' '));
};

var seconds = [
  ['0', '1'],
  ['0', '2'],
  ['0', '3'],
  ['0', '4'],
  ['0', '5'],
  ['0', '6'],
  ['0', '7'],
  ['0', '8'],
  ['0', '9'],
  ['1', '0'],
];

$.each(seconds, function(sec, num) {

  setTimeout(function() {

    $('.s-1 > DIV, .s-2 > DIV').removeClassRegEx('n-');
    $('.s-1 > DIV').addClass('n-' + num[0]);
    $('.s-2 > DIV').addClass('n-' + num[1]);

  }, 1000);

});
```

```css
.clock {
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  width: calc(40px*8);
  font-family: SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
  font-size: .8rem;
  color: #e83e8c;
}

.clock .h-1,
.clock .h-2,
.clock .m-1,
.clock .m-2,
.clock .s-1,
.clock .s-2 {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.clock .h-1:before,
.clock .h-2:before,
.clock .m-1:before,
.clock .m-2:before,
.clock .s-1:before,
.clock .s-2:before {
  content: "";
  padding-top: 150%;
  display: block;
}

.clock .h-1>DIV,
.clock .h-2>DIV,
.clock .m-1>DIV,
.clock .m-2>DIV,
.clock .s-1>DIV,
.clock .s-2>DIV {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.clock TIME {
  /* clock */
  float: left;
  width: calc(40px);
  height: calc(40px);
  display: block;
  background: #eeeeee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  /* the hands */
}

.clock TIME SPAN {
  position: absolute;
}

.clock TIME:before,
.clock TIME:after {
  border-radius: 1%;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 50%;
  background: #424242;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-1px);
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.n-0 .t-01:before{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-0 .t-01:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-0 .t-02:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-0 .t-02:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-0 .t-03:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-0 .t-03:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-0 .t-04:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-0 .t-04:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-0 .t-05:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-0 .t-05:after,.n-0 .t-06:before{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-0 .t-06:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-0 .t-07:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-0 .t-07:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-0 .t-08:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-0 .t-08:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-0 .t-09:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-0 .t-09:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-0 .t-10:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-0 .t-10:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-0 .t-11:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-0 .t-11:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-0 .t-12:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-0 .t-12:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-0 .t-13:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-0 .t-13:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-0 .t-14:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-0 .t-14:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-0 .t-15:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-0 .t-15:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-0 .t-16:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-0 .t-16:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-0 .t-17:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-0 .t-17:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-0 .t-18:before{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-0 .t-18:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-0 .t-19:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-0 .t-19:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-0 .t-20:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-0 .t-20:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-0 .t-21:before{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-0 .t-21:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-0 .t-22:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-0 .t-22:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-0 .t-23:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-0 .t-23:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-0 .t-24:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-0 .t-24:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-1 .t-01:before{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-1 .t-01:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-1 .t-02:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-1 .t-02:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-1 .t-03:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-1 .t-03:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-1 .t-04:after,.n-1 .t-04:before{transform:rotate(225deg)}.n-1 .t-05:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-1 .t-05:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-1 .t-06:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-1 .t-06:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-1 .t-07:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-1 .t-07:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-1 .t-08:after,.n-1 .t-08:before,.n-1 .t-09:after,.n-1 .t-09:before{transform:rotate(225deg)}.n-1 .t-10:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-1 .t-10:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-1 .t-11:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-1 .t-11:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-1 .t-12:after,.n-1 .t-12:before,.n-1 .t-13:after,.n-1 .t-13:before{transform:rotate(225deg)}.n-1 .t-14:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-1 .t-14:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-1 .t-15:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-1 .t-15:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-1 .t-16:after,.n-1 .t-16:before{transform:rotate(225deg)}.n-1 .t-17:before{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-1 .t-17:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-1 .t-18:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-1 .t-18:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-1 .t-19:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-1 .t-19:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-1 .t-20:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-1 .t-20:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-1 .t-21:before{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-1 .t-21:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-1 .t-22:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-1 .t-22:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-1 .t-23:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-1 .t-23:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-1 .t-24:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-1 .t-24:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-2 .t-01:before{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-2 .t-01:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-2 .t-02:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-2 .t-02:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-2 .t-03:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-2 .t-03:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-2 .t-04:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-2 .t-04:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-2 .t-05:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-2 .t-05:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-2 .t-06:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-2 .t-06:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-2 .t-07:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-2 .t-07:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-2 .t-08:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-2 .t-08:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-2 .t-09:before{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-2 .t-09:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-2 .t-10:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-2 .t-10:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-2 .t-11:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-2 .t-11:after{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-2 .t-12:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-2 .t-12:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-2 .t-13:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-2 .t-13:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-2 .t-14:before{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-2 .t-14:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-2 .t-15:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-2 .t-15:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-2 .t-16:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-2 .t-16:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-2 .t-17:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-2 .t-17:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-2 .t-18:before{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-2 .t-18:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-2 .t-19:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-2 .t-19:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-2 .t-20:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-2 .t-20:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-2 .t-21:before{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-2 .t-21:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-2 .t-22:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-2 .t-22:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-2 .t-23:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-2 .t-23:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-2 .t-24:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-2 .t-24:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-3 .t-01:before{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-3 .t-01:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-3 .t-02:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-3 .t-02:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-3 .t-03:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-3 .t-03:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-3 .t-04:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-3 .t-04:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-3 .t-05:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-3 .t-05:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-3 .t-06:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-3 .t-06:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-3 .t-07:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-3 .t-07:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-3 .t-08:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-3 .t-08:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-3 .t-09:before{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-3 .t-09:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-3 .t-10:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-3 .t-10:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-3 .t-11:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-3 .t-11:after{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-3 .t-12:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-3 .t-12:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-3 .t-13:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-3 .t-13:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-3 .t-14:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-3 .t-14:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-3 .t-15:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-3 .t-15:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-3 .t-16:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-3 .t-16:after,.n-3 .t-17:before{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-3 .t-17:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-3 .t-18:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-3 .t-18:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-3 .t-19:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-3 .t-19:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-3 .t-20:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-3 .t-20:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-3 .t-21:before{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-3 .t-21:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-3 .t-22:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-3 .t-22:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-3 .t-23:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-3 .t-23:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-3 .t-24:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-3 .t-24:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-4 .t-01:before{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-4 .t-01:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-4 .t-02:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-4 .t-02:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-4 .t-03:after,.n-4 .t-03:before,.n-4 .t-04:after,.n-4 .t-04:before{transform:rotate(225deg)}.n-4 .t-05:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-4 .t-05:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-4 .t-06:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-4 .t-06:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-4 .t-07:after,.n-4 .t-07:before,.n-4 .t-08:after,.n-4 .t-08:before{transform:rotate(225deg)}.n-4 .t-09:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-4 .t-09:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-4 .t-10:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-4 .t-10:after,.n-4 .t-11:before{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-4 .t-11:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-4 .t-12:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-4 .t-12:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-4 .t-13:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-4 .t-13:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-4 .t-14:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-4 .t-14:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-4 .t-15:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-4 .t-15:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-4 .t-16:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-4 .t-16:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-4 .t-17:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-4 .t-17:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-4 .t-18:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-4 .t-18:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-4 .t-19:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-4 .t-19:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-4 .t-20:before{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-4 .t-20:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-4 .t-21:after,.n-4 .t-21:before,.n-4 .t-22:after,.n-4 .t-22:before{transform:rotate(225deg)}.n-4 .t-23:before{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-4 .t-23:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-4 .t-24:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-4 .t-24:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-5 .t-01:before{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-5 .t-01:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-5 .t-02:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-5 .t-02:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-5 .t-03:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-5 .t-03:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-5 .t-04:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-5 .t-04:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-5 .t-05:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-5 .t-05:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-5 .t-06:before{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-5 .t-06:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-5 .t-07:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-5 .t-07:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-5 .t-08:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-5 .t-08:after{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-5 .t-09:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-5 .t-09:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-5 .t-10:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-5 .t-10:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-5 .t-11:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-5 .t-11:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-5 .t-12:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-5 .t-12:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-5 .t-13:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-5 .t-13:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-5 .t-14:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-5 .t-14:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-5 .t-15:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-5 .t-15:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-5 .t-16:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-5 .t-16:after,.n-5 .t-17:before{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-5 .t-17:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-5 .t-18:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-5 .t-18:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-5 .t-19:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-5 .t-19:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-5 .t-20:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-5 .t-20:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-5 .t-21:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-5 .t-21:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-5 .t-22:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-5 .t-22:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-5 .t-23:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-5 .t-23:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-5 .t-24:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-5 .t-24:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-6 .t-01:before{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-6 .t-01:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-6 .t-02:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-6 .t-02:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-6 .t-03:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-6 .t-03:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-6 .t-04:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-6 .t-04:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-6 .t-05:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-6 .t-05:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-6 .t-06:before{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-6 .t-06:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-6 .t-07:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-6 .t-07:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-6 .t-08:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-6 .t-08:after{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-6 .t-09:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-6 .t-09:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-6 .t-10:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-6 .t-10:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-6 .t-11:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-6 .t-11:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-6 .t-12:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-6 .t-12:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-6 .t-13:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-6 .t-13:after,.n-6 .t-14:before{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-6 .t-14:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-6 .t-15:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-6 .t-15:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-6 .t-16:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-6 .t-16:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-6 .t-17:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-6 .t-17:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-6 .t-18:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-6 .t-18:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-6 .t-19:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-6 .t-19:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-6 .t-20:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-6 .t-20:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-6 .t-21:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-6 .t-21:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-6 .t-22:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-6 .t-22:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-6 .t-23:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-6 .t-23:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-6 .t-24:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-6 .t-24:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-7 .t-01:before{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-7 .t-01:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-7 .t-02:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-7 .t-02:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-7 .t-03:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-7 .t-03:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-7 .t-04:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-7 .t-04:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-7 .t-05:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-7 .t-05:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-7 .t-06:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-7 .t-06:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-7 .t-07:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-7 .t-07:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-7 .t-08:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-7 .t-08:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-7 .t-09:after,.n-7 .t-09:before,.n-7 .t-10:after,.n-7 .t-10:before{transform:rotate(225deg)}.n-7 .t-11:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-7 .t-11:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-7 .t-12:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-7 .t-12:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-7 .t-13:after,.n-7 .t-13:before,.n-7 .t-14:after,.n-7 .t-14:before{transform:rotate(225deg)}.n-7 .t-15:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-7 .t-15:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-7 .t-16:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-7 .t-16:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-7 .t-17:after,.n-7 .t-17:before,.n-7 .t-18:after,.n-7 .t-18:before{transform:rotate(225deg)}.n-7 .t-19:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-7 .t-19:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-7 .t-20:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-7 .t-20:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-7 .t-21:after,.n-7 .t-21:before,.n-7 .t-22:after,.n-7 .t-22:before{transform:rotate(225deg)}.n-7 .t-23:before{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-7 .t-23:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-7 .t-24:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-7 .t-24:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-8 .t-01:before{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-8 .t-01:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-8 .t-02:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-8 .t-02:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-8 .t-03:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-8 .t-03:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-8 .t-04:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-8 .t-04:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-8 .t-05:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-8 .t-05:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-8 .t-06:before{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-8 .t-06:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-8 .t-07:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-8 .t-07:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-8 .t-08:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-8 .t-08:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-8 .t-09:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-8 .t-09:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-8 .t-10:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-8 .t-10:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-8 .t-11:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-8 .t-11:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-8 .t-12:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-8 .t-12:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-8 .t-13:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-8 .t-13:after,.n-8 .t-14:before{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-8 .t-14:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-8 .t-15:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-8 .t-15:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-8 .t-16:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-8 .t-16:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-8 .t-17:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-8 .t-17:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-8 .t-18:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-8 .t-18:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-8 .t-19:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-8 .t-19:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-8 .t-20:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-8 .t-20:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-8 .t-21:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-8 .t-21:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-8 .t-22:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-8 .t-22:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-8 .t-23:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-8 .t-23:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-8 .t-24:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-8 .t-24:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-9 .t-01:before{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-9 .t-01:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-9 .t-02:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-9 .t-02:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-9 .t-03:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-9 .t-03:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-9 .t-04:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-9 .t-04:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-9 .t-05:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-9 .t-05:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-9 .t-06:before{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-9 .t-06:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-9 .t-07:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-9 .t-07:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-9 .t-08:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-9 .t-08:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-9 .t-09:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-9 .t-09:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-9 .t-10:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-9 .t-10:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-9 .t-11:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-9 .t-11:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-9 .t-12:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-9 .t-12:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-9 .t-13:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-9 .t-13:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-9 .t-14:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-9 .t-14:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-9 .t-15:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-9 .t-15:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-9 .t-16:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-9 .t-16:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-9 .t-17:before{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-9 .t-17:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-9 .t-18:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-9 .t-18:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-9 .t-19:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-9 .t-19:after{transform:rotate(0)}.n-9 .t-20:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-9 .t-20:after{transform:rotate(180deg)}.n-9 .t-21:before{transform:rotate(360deg)}.n-9 .t-21:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-9 .t-22:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-9 .t-22:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-9 .t-23:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-9 .t-23:after{transform:rotate(90deg)}.n-9 .t-24:before{transform:rotate(270deg)}.n-9 .t-24:after{transform:rotate(0)}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clock">

  <div class="seconds">
    <div class="s-1">
      <div class="n-0">
        <time class="t-01"></time>
        <time class="t-02"></time>
        <time class="t-03"></time>
        <time class="t-04"></time>
        <time class="t-05"></time>
        <time class="t-06"></time>
        <time class="t-07"></time>
        <time class="t-08"></time>
        <time class="t-09"></time>
        <time class="t-10"></time>
        <time class="t-11"></time>
        <time class="t-12"></time>
        <time class="t-13"></time>
        <time class="t-14"></time>
        <time class="t-15"></time>
        <time class="t-16"></time>
        <time class="t-17"></time>
        <time class="t-18"></time>
        <time class="t-19"></time>
        <time class="t-20"></time>
        <time class="t-21"></time>
        <time class="t-22"></time>
        <time class="t-23"></time>
        <time class="t-24"></time>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="s-2">
    <div class="n-1">
      <time class="t-01"></time>
      <time class="t-02"></time>
      <time class="t-03"></time>
      <time class="t-04"></time>
      <time class="t-05"></time>
      <time class="t-06"></time>
      <time class="t-07"></time>
      <time class="t-08"></time>
      <time class="t-09"></time>
      <time class="t-10"></time>
      <time class="t-11"></time>
      <time class="t-12"></time>
      <time class="t-13"></time>
      <time class="t-14"></time>
      <time class="t-15"></time>
      <time class="t-16"></time>
      <time class="t-17"></time>
      <time class="t-18"></time>
      <time class="t-19"></time>
      <time class="t-20"></time>
      <time class="t-21"></time>
      <time class="t-22"></time>
      <time class="t-23"></time>
      <time class="t-24"></time>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: appreciate you, for the css you wrote with patience. @joshmoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really liked your idea. Inspired by it, I created the POC below:

https://jsfiddle.net/abinthaha/62wuzvx3/28/

```
getValue();
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    getValue();
}, 1000);

function getValue() {
    var date = new Date();
    val = date.getSeconds();
    val = parseInt(val) + 1;
    val = getSec(val);
    setValue(val);
}

function setValue(val) {
        $('.s-1 > DIV, .s-2 > DIV').removeClassRegEx('n-');
        $('.s-1 > DIV').addClass('n-' + parseInt(val / 10));
        $('.s-2 > DIV').addClass('n-' + parseInt(val % 10));
}

function getSec(num) {
    if (num < 10 || num == 0) {
        num = '0' + num;
    } else if (num >= 60) {
        num = num % 60;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: This is awesome, getting the seconds from the current date and the math on the `setValue` is genius!  I'm still trying to understand the `getSec` function but its magic mate. Thanks.

Comment: I don't suppose you could help me make this into a clock using your same logic? https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/rnq1mvfs/

Comment: Thanks mahn, I can help you do the same. I am so happy to. Let me work on it and will update it once I am done

Comment: Hi, This is something I did with Hours, minutes, and seconds. But the alignment is now column wise, Need to work on it to show it in a row. Please use it. https://jsfiddle.net/abinthaha/n4tL0ok2/2/

Comment: Hey abinthaha sorry i just got round to looking at this. This is awesome dude, thank you very much. I will use this. Works so good. Again thank you!

Comment: My pleasure. The CSS you wrote is so awesome. I really liked the way it works and that was such an inspiration.

Comment: Same with your script too. I've also cleaned up the sass and added some options https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/u5bL3g8j/

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` is non-blocking. It only specifies a callback function to be called after a specified amount of time, but any code after it will be immediately executed, regardless of the delay specified.

This means that in your example, since the execution of `setTimeout` (not its callback) does not block the execution of the loop, all `setTimeout` statements are executed right after each other, so the delays are not staggered.

A simple solution would be to multiply the `sec` parameter of the loop callback by the specified delay in `setTimeout`:

```
$.each(seconds, function(sec, num) {

  setTimeout(function() {

    $('.s-1 > DIV, .s-2 > DIV').removeClassRegEx('n-');
    $('.s-1 > DIV').addClass('n-' + num[0]);
    $('.s-2 > DIV').addClass('n-' + num[1]);

  }, (sec+1)*1000);

});
```

JSFiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/j76bwrpv/2/[1](https://jsfiddle.net/j76bwrpv/2/)

Answer (score 0):

try to place setTimeOut at the end of loop:

```
$.each(seconds, function(sec, num) {

    $('.s-1 > DIV, .s-2 > DIV').removeClassRegEx('n-');
    $('.s-1 > DIV').addClass('n-' + num[0]);
    $('.s-2 > DIV').addClass('n-' + num[1]);

   setTimeout(function() {}, 1000);

});
```

Comment: This won't work. The content *within* the timeout will be delayed, but the `$.each()` will continue to iterate immediately.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, very simple counter, Here is the working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vp654g7z/)

```
// remove class regex
$.fn.removeClassRegEx = function(regex) {
    var classes = $(this).attr('class');
    if (!classes || !regex) return false;
    var classArray = [];
    classes = classes.split(' ');
    for (var i = 0, len = classes.length; i < len; i++)
        if (!classes[i].match(regex)) classArray.push(classes[i]);
    $(this).attr('class', classArray.join(' '));
};

var seconds = [
    ['0', '1'],
    ['0', '2'],
    ['0', '3'],
    ['0', '4'],
    ['0', '5'],
    ['0', '6'],
    ['0', '7'],
    ['0', '8'],
    ['0', '9'],
    ['1', '0'],
];

var i = 0;                     

function myLoop () {           
   setTimeout(function () {    

      i++;               
       console.log(i);//  increment the counter
     $('.s-2 > DIV').removeClassRegEx('n-');

    $('.s-2 > DIV').addClass('n-' + i);
      if (i < 10) {   

         myLoop();            
      }

   }, 1000)
}

myLoop();
```